# Showing $\mathbb{R}$ is a completion of $(\mathbb{Q}, | \cdot |)$

Tags: general-topology

Recall the definition of a completion: A complete metric space $(Y, d)$ is said to be a *completion* of another metric space $(X, d)$ if there exists a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ such that

1. $f$ is an isometry of $X$ into $Y$, and
2. the image $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$.

Recall an isometry is a map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ such that for all $a, b$ in $X$, we have $d_{X}(a, b) = d_{Y}(f(a), f(b))$.

So, choose $f(x) = x$, then $d(a, b) = |a - b| = |f(a) - f(b)| = d(f(a), f(b))$, so we found an isometry, and we know that $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$ (this is clear from our choice of $f$, every point is a fixed point) is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: How did you define $\Bbb R$ to begin with?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb R$ is just the set of real numbers, and $\Bbb Q$ is the set of rationals.

Comment: I know what $\Bbb R$ denotes, but how do you define it?

Comment: I'm not sure of how my definition of the set of reals is important here.

Comment: @LonelyMathematician It is important because $\Bbb R$ is usually axiomatically defined and/or constructed to be the completion of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Well, to be honest then, I'm not really sure how to answer that question. The title of the post here is exactly the question in the book, and we haven't defined $\Bbb R$ to be the completion of $\Bbb Q$ in this course.

Comment: Doesn't the book define $\Bbb R$ at all? What book is it?

Comment: Topology of Metric Spaces by Kumaresan. All I know is that in the course we haven't really defined the reals. Does this really affect whether or not my argument is valid?